# Отправка данных полученных из EditText

Tags: android

Куски кода:

```
nameText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.nameText);
name = nameText.toString();
new RequestTask().execute("http://example.org/Script.php?test=" + name);

class RequestTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... uri) {
        try {
            HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            String getURL = uri[0];
            HttpGet get = new HttpGet(getURL);
            HttpResponse responseGet = client.execute(get);
            HttpEntity resEntityGet = responseGet.getEntity();
            if (resEntityGet != null) {
                Log.i("GET RESPONSE", EntityUtils.toString(resEntityGet));
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
    }
}
```

Пхп скрипт сохраняет в базу этот стринг, а в базе уже получаеться нечто подобное `android.widget.EditText@47682d50`. В чем проблема? Как сохранить в базу нормальные строчки?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Всё правильно. Нужно не nameText.toString, а что-то типа nameText.getText() или nameText.getValue ( не вкурсе просто ) А то вы пытаетесь едитТекст(компоненту) получить в виде строки

Comment: Блин точно, ночь, туплю жутко. Сенкс.